# Convert application context to Java Config Springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, applicationcontext

Looking for some guidance on converting below in existing applicationContext.xml into Java Config for a new Springboot application.

```
<bean id="InitialHandler" class="package.InitialHandler" 
  scope="prototype">
  <property name="rawResponseTemplate" 
   ref="rawResponseRestTemplate"/>
  <property name="mimeMapper" ref="initialMimeMapper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="rawResponseRestTemplate" 
   class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
  <property name="messageConverters">
    <list>
        <bean class="package.CommonDocumentRawMessageConverter"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="initialMimeMapper" 
class="package.ConfigurationBasedMapper">
  <property name="configuration" ref="initialMimeConfig"/>
</bean>

<bean id="initialMimeConfig" 
class="org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLPropertiesConfiguration" 
scope="singleton">
  <constructor-arg type="java.net.URL" 
 value="classpath:FileINeedLoaded.xml"/>
  <property name="reloadingStrategy" ref="ReloadingStrategy"/>
</bean>

// snippet of CommonDocumentRawMessageConverter below
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
public class CommonDocumentRawMessageConverter implements 
  HttpMessageConverter<CommonDocument>  {}
```

This is what i have:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate rawResponseRestTemplate() {
    RestTemplate rawResponseRestTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    rawResponseRestTemplate.setMessageConverters(msgConverters());    
    return rawResponseRestTemplate;
}

private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> msgConverters() {
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> newList = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    newList.add(new CommonDocumentRawMessageConverter());
    return newList;
}
```

Service compiles OK but get runtime exception as follows:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'prop.mime-mapper' to 
package.util.Mapper<java.lang.String>:

Property: prop.mime-mapper
Value: propMimeMapper
Origin: "prop.mimeMapper" from property source "Config resource 'class 
path resource [application.yml]' via location 'optional:classpath:/' 
(document #0)"
Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No 
converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to 
type [package.util.Mapper<java.lang.String>]

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Snippet of my config:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class propConfig {
   private String randomProp;
   private Mapper<String> mimeMapper;
   private RestTemplate rawResponseTemplate;
```

Service:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class PropService extends DocumentManagementService {

private final RestTemplate rawResponseTemplate;
private final Mapper<String> mimeMapper;

public PropService(@Autowired PropConfig propConfig) {
    this.rawResponseTemplate = propConfig.getRawResponseTemplate();
    this.mimeMapper = propConfig.getMimeMapper();
}
```

It appears that at runtime the properties defined as RestTemplate and Mapper are not getting converted for some reason.

**UPDATE ONE**
I was able to fix above issue by removing these properties from the application.yaml altogether.

```
private Mapper<String> mimeMapper;
private RestTemplate rawResponseTemplate;
```

I realised that these properties were actually 'refs' in the original applicationContext.xml and thus not required in the new application.yaml.  I do have new issues however related to this conversion which i will share. I will keep original configs in place in case others have same issue.

Comment: The `<bean>` tag could just be an annotated `@bean` (i.e. SpringBean) in your Converter tag - see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.  Not sure what you mean, how would it look?

Comment: A bean in XML can be replaced by a java (spring) bean (annotated as per link) - if you need more, it's best to add more details to your question.  You can also search for spring beans examples for samples on how to do it

Comment: Thanks have been reading resources online but couldn't see anything that covered beans with properties containing a list of beans, so not sure if above is correct even though it compiles OK. updated post with proposed changes.

Comment: The updated changes look OK at first glance but I have no time to create a mini-project and compile it, see it work.  The one thing I noticed is that you have not declared a bean for `CommonDocumentRawMessageConverter` - is that defined somewhere else in the package or code?

Comment: That's ok appreciate your response. yeah that one is in it's own class i.e.:                     
@Slf4j
public class CommonDocumentRawMessageConverter implements HttpMessageConverter<CommonDocument>  {

Comment: Looks good. What is the error?

Comment: I've updated the post with error and further info.  initial snippet of applicationContext.xml is what i'm trying to replace with JavaConfig.

Comment: New issues encountered are unrelated to above issue so will work through those offline and raise new one if i get stuck.  Thanks for those who responded appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix above issue by removing these properties from the application.yaml altogether.

```
private Mapper<String> mimeMapper;
private RestTemplate rawResponseTemplate;
```

I realised that these properties were actually 'refs' in the original applicationContext.xml and thus not required in the new application.yaml.